# Does a vector get copied on return?

Tags: c++, vector

I had a whole pile of trouble with objects getting destroyed(and their heap data along with them) when returning vectors from functions a while back. I don't remember the exact details so I tried returning a vector of objects today and their destructor didn't get triggered.

Do I remember it wrong? If i made a vector like this:

```
std::vector<myObject> MakeVectorOfMyObjects(int size) {
    std::vector<myObject> ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ret.push_back(myObject());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and called it like that:

```
std::vector<myObject> stuff = MakeVectorOfMyObjects(5);
```

Is it guaranteed that the the vector that now resides in "stuff" is the exact same as the one i built in the function without any of the objects getting destroyed, remade or otherwise manipulated during the return and assignment?

Also does it make any difference whether I pass a vector to a function by reference or by value?

EDIT: getting a bit vague answers so let me rephrase: 
How to I guarantee that the the vector in "stuff" is the same pile of bits as the one I created in the function? (outside creating the vector with new keyword and returning the pointer that is)

Comment: You're pretty much guaranteed that in this case. Compilers are good at that optimization. In C++11, it falls back to moving the vector out instead of copying it.

Comment: More the likely the compiler used [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) or [Move Semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics) if you are using C++11

Answer (score 0):

*Is it guaranteed that the the vector that now resides in "stuff" is the exact same as the one i built in the function without any of the objects getting destroyed, remade or otherwise manipulated during the return and assignment?*

No. But it CAN be. This is due to optional return value optimization. Well-written code must work in either case.

*Also does it make any difference whether I pass a vector to a function by reference or by value?*

Yes. The rules for passing a vector by reference or value are the same as for any class.

Comment: Well, in some cases, the vector type seems to function more like a pointer than a value type so I figured I'd check.

Comment: "Yes. One is a copy and one isn't." -- Except not. If you pass by value it could be moved.

Comment: Could you give an example of when it functions like a pointer?

Comment: @Jefffrey You are right.

Comment: @NeilKirk well, all arrays are passed as pointers, the vector is a collections like an array

Comment: @user81993, Fortunately, `std::vector` doesn't inherit any of the pointer-like qualities of an array.

Answer (score 0):

When you returning local vector "ret" object from function it'll be copied (or moved in case of C++11) into the local object "stuff".

You shouldn't do anything special for it, this is how works "returning by value" mechanism.

Comment: It's possible that it is neither copied nor moved.